# CSV - Deleting lines containing numbers with wrong structure

Tags: csv

Good afternoon all,
I was saving data from oscilloscope to USB stick as point delimited coma separated files and apparently there was some problem with transfer resulting in appearance of lines that do not match "usual" numerical format. It is hard to explain, easier to show:

```
1.788400e-04,0.008,0.006,0.008
1.788600e-04,-0.008,0.002,0.02
1.788800e-04,0.016,0.002,0
1.789200e-04,0,0.002.673200e-04,0.008,0.012,0.12
1.673400e-04,0,-0.002,0.008
1.673600e-04,0,0.01,0.012
1.673800e-04,0.008,0.002,0.008
```

What I mean is the `0.002.673200e-04` on 4th row. Luckily it is not too frequent and lines such as this can be deleted. It is however hard to find as the files are around million lines. First I thought it would be easy to do by locating the `.002.` and deleting it using:

```
grep -v ".002." testfile.csv > testfile-fixed.csv
```

This indeed worked, however the number between the dots changes. So far I managed to find `.000.` and `.002.` and it may not be limited to those two.

The other thing that changes is the number of columns.

Is there some easy way to get rid of these lines?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to delete all the lines containing a number with two dots, I suggest you to use `sed` instead of `grep`.

```
sed '/\.[0-9]*\./d' testfile.csv > testfile-fixed.csv
```

This command deletes the line matching the regex `\.[0-9]*\.`, which matches all the lines containing a dot followed by 0 or more digits and followed by a dot.

You can even do the change inside the file itself, but if you make a mistake, you can destroy your file, so make first a backup. Use the flag `-i` with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/\.[0-9]*\./d' testfile.csv
```

Comment: @Francois, thank you, I used sed and it did exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately the file seems to be corrupt a bit more then expected. After deleting the .00x. I still got some errors and found, by manually going through million lines that there was one line with just two columns:
`1.284860e-03,0.008,-0.006,0.016 XX
1.284880e-03,0.008,0.01,0.016 XX
1.284900e-0.2 XX
1.273300e-03,0.008,0.006,0.012 XX
1.273320e-03,-0.016,-0.002,0.02` 
would there be an elegant way how to keep in only those lines having 4 columns? XX as end of line Thank you

Comment: @JirkaPachman: With `sed`, you can also delete all the lines that do not contain exactly 3 commas.

Comment: @Francois, good point. I however found elegant solution using awk:
`awk -F, 'NF==4' testfile.csv > testfile-fixed.csv`

Comment: @JirkaPachman: The `awk` solution is perfect.